# Using gsub with pattern and x as vector

Tags: r, data.table, substring, character

I'm facing this problem, let's `db` a `data.table` object defined as below :

```
              X    Y
1:     Joe Snow  Joe
2: Sony Ericson Sony
3:    JP Morgan   JP
4:     KATAKURI   NA
```

I want then to delete `Y` from `X`, like this :

```
db[!is.na(Y), Z := sub(pattern = Y, replacement = "", x = X)]
```

As you can imagine, it does not work, because `sub` accepts only a single character as `pattern`. 
I tried this trick, but does not work :

```
db[, pos := 1]
db[!is.na(Y), Z := sub(pattern = Y, replacement = "", x = X), by = .(pos)]
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: try this `paste(Y, collapse="|")`?

Comment: No it's not the good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for corresponding elements of 'X' and 'Y' in the `sub` then `Map` can be used

```
db[!is.na(Y), Z := unlist(Map(sub, pattern = Y, X, replacement = ""))]
db
#             X    Y        Z
#1:     Joe Snow  Joe     Snow
#2: Sony Ericson Sony  Ericson
#3:    JP Morgan   JP   Morgan
#4:     KATAKURI   NA       NA
```

---

Or another option is `map/pmap` functions from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
db %>%
   set_names(c('x', 'pattern')) %>% 
   pmap_chr(., sub, replacement = '') %>% 
   trimws %>%
   bind_cols(db, z = .)
#              X    Y       z
#1:     Joe Snow  Joe    Snow
#2: Sony Ericson Sony Ericson
#3:    JP Morgan   JP  Morgan
#4:     KATAKURI   NA      NA
```

Comment: It works, thank you !